# Cursor on Macbook Pro stucks (or trembling without response)

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, cursor

I have a very weird issue on my MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014). While using the trackpad, mouse cursor stuck or becomes super laggy for no reason. The only way to come back is if I will close and open the lid of the screen, even super-fast without letting it go to sleep mode.

I am checking Console for errors but I can't see any pattern there... Do you have any clue how to trace the ERROR or what is the source?

Comment: I had similar weird behavior. It turned out to have trivial and totally unrelated cause. I had a magic trackpad also paired and it was forgotten in a drawer, though somehow turned on by stuff in the drawer.  Could you check and maybe disconnect other bluetooth and usb input devices next time it happens?

Comment: I am keeping bluetooth connection disabled and it still happens..